# MySQL Query Optimization for the derived & Sub Query Combination queries

Tags: mysql, query-optimization, high-traffic

The following sort of the queries are running on the server which uses the derived table and subquery. The constraint is that the subqueries are generated from the multiple modules based on the current situation so cannot really convert it into the join combination.

Please suggest the possible solution to optimize the query

```
 SELECT COUNT(1) 
 AS total 
 FROM member tlb_m
 where tlb_m.active = 1 
 and tlb_m.rank > 0 
 and tlb_m.member_id not in (5735,134,241,1055,348,272,476,43,7,804,7548,90,229,346,40895) 
 and tlb_m.type = 'M' 
 and (tlb_m.hometown_list_id in 
  (SELECT l2.list_id  
    FROM ((
      SELECT t12.list_id 
      from list_tree_idx t12 
      INNER JOIN list_tree_idx t11 
      ON t12.list_parent_id=t11.list_id 
      where t11.list_parent_id='205546' 
    ) UNION ALL (
      SELECT list_id 
      from list_tree_idx 
      where list_parent_id='205546'
    ) ) as l2 
  ) or tlb_m.hometown_list_id = 205546
)
```

Comment: Always include the output of `EXPLAIN` when asking for query optimization, along with storage engine used and configuration variables.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use a [closure table](https://kylecordes.com/2008/transitive-closure) for optimal hierarchical queries.
For example, having a closure table with columns ANCESTOR_ID, CHILD_ID and DEPTH your query will look like this

```
SELECT COUNT(1) AS total 
  FROM member AS tlb_m
  LEFT JOIN hometown_closure AS c ON c.child_id = tlb_m.hometown_list_id
  where tlb_m.active = 1 
    and tlb_m.rank > 0 
    and tlb_m.member_id not in (5735,134,241,1055,348,272,476,43,7,804,7548,90,229,346,40895) 
    and tlb_m.type = 'M' 
    and c.ancestor_id = 205546
```